# Python regex. Removing all characters after ':' (including at the end of line and except for a specific string)

Tags: python, regex, parsing, python-3.5

I'm parsing info and layout data from a log file. Say I have some lines that look like this:

> Book: 190 Checked Out By: ABCD-1234-E5F6, Status: LATE Return: 02.20.2018

I'm trying to remove the info specific to the line like numbers, serial, date, etc. However, say the 'Status: LATE' should stay. I want output like:

> Book Checked Out By, Status: LATE Return

(This example is made up. It makes a little more sense with the actual data and task.)

Currently I have: `re.sub(':\s.*?(?=[^A-Z\d\-.])','', str)` to remove all characters following ': ' that are not a capital letter, a number, and a '.' or a '-' (it stops at anything else like whitespace, a-z, etc). However my output is leaving the last bit in the line and removes the Status.

> Book Checked Out By, Status: Return: 10.20.2018

1. How can I specify to remove all capital letters following a ': ' except for the word 'LATE'
2. What is missing that would remove the numbers at the end of a line too?

Comment: What about `:\s*(?!LATE)[\w-.]+(?=[\s,]|$)` or `:\s*(?!LATE)\S+?(?=[\s,]|$)`?

Comment: You say the example is made up - can you just clarify that it's actually representative of the data you're actually working with? Also - what is the output you're ultimately after?

Comment: The second one from ctwheels works! Thanks.

Comment: @JonClements - I'm doing QA for the audit logs and making sure certain events are actually being logged. I'm trying to erase numbers and data that would be specific to a particular test cases (product serial number, ip addresses, etc.) so that I will have only general events left over to diff with the expected output.

Comment: Ahh okay... just wondering if it made sense to parse the line, then remove identifying info... or, if you know what you're looking for - then just look for that specifically...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`re.sub` with a negative lookahead to keep `LATE` out of match:

```
re.sub(r':\s(?!LATE)[A-Z\d.-]+', '', str_)
```

- `:\s` matches `:` followed by one whitespace
- `(?!LATE)` -- the zero width negative lookahead makes sure `LATE` does not occur in the following match
- `[A-Z\d.-]+` matches one or more of `[A-Z\d.-]`

**Example:**

```
In [41]: str_ = 'Book: 190 Checked Out By: ABCD-1234-E5F6, Status: LATE Return: 02.20.2018'

In [42]: re.sub(r':\s(?!LATE)[A-Z\d.-]+', '', str_)
Out[42]: 'Book Checked Out By, Status: LATE Return'
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this works the exact way I need it to.